# postgres.ECPG : is 'COPY datas FROM :file_name' possible?

Tags: postgresql

I'm coding a C++ application that needs to interact with a postgres DB. 
I would like to initialize the table **datas** using a COPY statement.

Here's the code :

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION ;
  const char * fileData_name = file_data_name ;
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION ;

EXEC SQL COPY datas
         FROM :fileData_name
         WITH (FORMAT text, DELIMITER '|') ;
```

Here's  the error message from ecpg :

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ":fileData_name"
```

According to the postgres [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-variables.html) : 
*This style of inserting C variables in SQL statements works anywhere a **value expression** is expected in an SQL statement.*

If COPY *stuff* FROM *field*, then my guess is that *field* is not a value expression.

Any help ?

thx :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not possible to do that... according to [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5454/postgres-plpgsql-using-a-variable-inside-of-a-dynamic-create-statement). But it's possible to use prepared statements :

```
char * sql_template = 
    "COPY datas FROM '%s' WITH (FORMAT text, DELIMITER '|');" ;
const char * file_name = "myfile.data";
unsigned int sql_command_len = 
    strlen (sql_template) - 2 + strlen (file_name) + 1;

EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION ; 
    char * sql_command = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*sql_command_len) ; 
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION ; 

sprintf (sql_command, sql_template, file_name) ;

EXEC SQL PREPARE cpy FROM :sql_command;
EXEC SQL EXECUTE cpy ;
EXEC SQL DEALLOCATE PREPARE cpy ;
free (sql_command) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just single quotes the :fileData_name variable according the [PostgreSQL documetation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html):

```
EXEC SQL COPY datas
         FROM ':fileData_name'
         WITH (FORMAT text, DELIMITER '|') ;
```